# What is the difference of openjdk 11 vs Amazon Corretto 11 in 2022?

Tags: openjdk-11, corretto

What is the difference between those? Which one should we choose if we have our servers in aws?

There is 3 vulnerabilities in corretto version that does not exist in openjdk version. So can we assume that corretto is always a bit lagged behind openjdk?

Or does corretto have some other benefits?